# Why is cin operation undefined?

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

main()
{

    bool string1[20];
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    cin >> string1;
    int counter = 0;
    int length;
    length = strlen(string1);
```

This is incomplete code, but my question is why am I getting a compiling error when using `cin`? It says:

> error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘bool [20]’)

On this line:

```
 cin >> string1;
```

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting someone to enter with `bool string1[20]`? Are you expecting your user to input something like "true", or like `0101010101101`?

Comment: I want them to input a string of characters or numbers like gfc098

Comment: Then why do you have a `bool` array? Why not use `std::string` like you included?

Comment: Didn't think of that but it doesn't seem to solve the compile error

Comment: when i change it to a string the compile error shows up as  error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘st                                                                                            d::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘std::string [20] {aka std::basic                                                                                            _string<char> [20]}’)
     cin >> string1;  I still have the cin error

Comment: @Joe you need to change `bool string1[20];` to either `char string1[20];` or `string string1;` not to `string string1[20];`

Comment: Get a C++ book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

`bool string1[20];` is the wrong choice for the user input as a string, all it does is create an array of `20`booleans, `true` or `false` which is not what you want.

what you are after is your included `#include <string>`

```
string string1;
cout << "Enter string: ";
cin >> string1;
```

Instead of using `strlen` you get the length by using the `length` method provided by `std::string`

`auto length = string1.length()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `operator>>` for reading an array of `bool` values. What you need is an array of `char` values instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char string1[20];
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    cin >> setw(20) >> string1;
    int length = strlen(string1);
```

Or better, a single `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string string1;
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    cin >> string1;
    int length = string1.length();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confusing string with array. string1 in your code is not an string its an array. So, you can't just put data in it without giving the proper index number. Also remember its an bool type so you can only enter 0/1/true/false value.

Again, you have used strlen() function in your code which is used for determining the length of the string but your is an array. You didn't ask about this but when I ran the code in my IDE it got error.

Here is one way to do it :

```
    main()
    {
        bool string1[20];
        cout << "Enter string: ";
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)//iterating through the boolian array
        {
            cin >> string1[i];
        }
        int counter = 0;
        int length;
        length = sizeof(string1)/sizeof(string1[0]);
        cout<<length;//printing the size of the array
    }
```